# LINQ - select by property name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following class:

```
public class User
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
}
```

Sample:

```
{
   userName: John,
   active: true
},
{
   userName: Mary,
   active: true
}
```

How do I query "active" users by the property name?
This is what I've tried, but I get:

*"The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()"*

```
Type t = typeof(User);
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("active");

int totalActive = userContext.Users.Where(u => Convert.ToBoolean(p.GetValue(u)) == true).Count();
```

Comment: Don't you know the name of the property at compile-time? Why is that? Anyway, client evaluation should work as the message suggests (e.g., `userContext.Users.ToList().Where(...)`).

Comment: First `active` is not a Property... It is a field. `GetProperty` won’t find it. Second... Why is reflection required when `u` and `t` are the same type.

Comment: @LegacyCode - Well, it is an AutoProperty.

Comment: @MineKrafter It was't when I replied to it. janzen changed it to autoproperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you need to call AsEnumerable() before trying to filter the data in the Where clause.

```
Type t = typeof(User);
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("active");

int totalActive = userContext.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(u => Convert.ToBoolean(p.GetValue(u)) == true).Count();
```

This is because linq will try to convert your expression into a sql query, and you are using a function on the where statment, linq will fail converting this expression beacuse the function does not exist on sql.

AsEnumerable() will force the query to run and pull the data into memory, then c# will apply the filtering.

Comment: I'd be very hesitant to use this against a database, especially if the *Users* table had a large number of rows..

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you need to perform this dynamically  you will need to build [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) (check [`Queryable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netcore-3.1) signature) manually:

```
public class User
{
    public string userName {get;set;}
    public bool active {get;set;}
}

Type t = typeof(User);
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("active");

var prmtr = Expression.Parameter(t);
var value = Expression.Constant(true);
var comprasion = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(prmtr, p), value);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(comprasion, prmtr);

int totalActive = userContext.Users.Where(expr).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalActive = userContext.Users.Where(u => u.active).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is a question about [Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval).

Because you use some methods in the where condition that are *not recognized on the sql server side*, you can convert all the current linq to **the client side** to execute.

That is add **`AsEnumerable()`** or **`ToList()`** to `userContext.Users`.

Example:

```
int totalActive = userContext.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(u => Convert.ToBoolean(p.GetValue(u)) == true).Count();
```

Another way, you can also convert all linq statements into **sql server-side** recognized statements for execution, as the answer provided by [@Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885471/12884742) above.